# A more efficient alternative to if statements

Tags: c#, performance, comparison

I have a desktop C# app.

I have a nested loop.

I am comparing values between to multi arrays using the 'if' statement.

this is my code:

```
            for (int x = 0; x < FRAME_HEIGHT; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < FRAME_WIDTH; y++)
                {
                    if ((Shared.MotionState[camIndex].PreviousGrid[y, x] != Shared.MotionState[camIndex].DiffCurrentPrevious[y, x]
                        && Shared.MotionState[camIndex].DiffCurrentPrevious[y, x] == 1)) 
                    {
                        diffGrids[camIndex][y, x] = 1;
                        diff++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        diffGrids[camIndex][y, x] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Now I know I could flatten the arrays but it will still need to use the if statements.

I am not saying there is anything wrong is this I am just asking whether this is the most memory efficient way of doing this.

N.B.
The diff grid is a static modular grid I have created at run-time.

Thanks

Comment: With the little information present here I don't see how you could use less memory for this. You could potentially turn the innermost array into a bitwise array, reducing the number of elements by 8, 16, or 32, depending on the size of its type. It would complicate access, but use less memory.

Comment: Hi, @LasseV.Karlsen thanks for replying.  Much appreciated. Sorry for the sparse code it really does come down to this because of constraints elsewhere.  I was just curious if there were better ways. Always looking to improve myself you see. Thanks again :)

Comment: we need to know what `DiffCurrentPrevious` does in order to help you. Worrying about using `if` is micro optimization and there be dragons!

Comment: Hi, the DiffCurrentPrevious and PreviousGrid variables are just more static int[,] arrays.  However, you both have answered my questions in regards to 'if' comparisons method which I thank you both for. This question, however, may need to be deleted now

Comment: It looks like you are trying to implement a video frame change detection algorithm. With `DiffCurrentPrevious` being a bit mask. It might be faster to invert the `&&`, or even if `DiffCurrentPrevious` is sparce you use that to index.

Comment: @Aron Excellent deduction.  Yes, i will inverse the && now.  Are you also suggesting in your latter comment a type of LUT?  thanks

Comment: Yes, converting it into a LUT might be faster. Especially if you can then loop through in the order of the LUT rather than by x, y, as then you can get better branch prediction. PS traditionally x is to denote width and y is to denote height (I think).

Comment: Cool. 'x' + 'y' lol. Yh, I have been lazy.  Forgot to rename variables.  Will do so now. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Also, with `camIndex` being loop invariant you could probably gain some speed by having locals for `Shared.MotionState[camIndex]` and `diffGrids[camIndex]`.

Comment: Hi, sounds interesting but not sure how to implement? I have 4 cameras and I pass the cam index to this function dependent on what camera frame I currently have. Pls explain as any improvement I can make I wish to do so. Thanks

Comment: I think @500-InternalServerError means before the outer For: `var motionState = Shared.MotionState[camIndex]; var diffGrid = diffGrids[camIndex];`. But I'm dubious whether this yields a measurable speed gain; the compiler/jitter probably does this automatically for loop invariant array offsets.